# Playwright install-deps fails in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, playwright, playwright-python

I have a small application that uses playwright to scrape data from various websites.
The application is Dockerized well and everything worked perfectly until I tried to re-build the Docker image (nothing really changed in the code) and it failed to install the playwright deps (like it used to before).

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

COPY ../../requirements/dev.txt ./

RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip install -r dev.txt
RUN playwright install 
RUN playwright install-deps 

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app/"
WORKDIR /code/src

EXPOSE 8000

COPY ./src /app

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--reload"]
```

This is the requirements:

```
fastapi>=0.85.0
uvicorn>=0.18.3
bs4==0.0.1
playwright
```

This is the error message:

```
 => ERROR [6/8] RUN playwright install-deps                                                                                                                                           4.1s 
------
 > [6/8] RUN playwright install-deps:
#10 0.762 BEWARE: your OS is not officially supported by Playwright; installing dependencies for Ubuntu as a fallback.
#10 0.762 Installing dependencies...
#10 1.084 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [147 kB]
#10 1.269 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
#10 1.338 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
#10 1.407 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages [8904 kB]
#10 2.278 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages [24.2 kB]
#10 3.063 Fetched 9176 kB in 2s (4021 kB/s)
#10 3.063 Reading package lists...
#10 3.474 Reading package lists...
#10 3.868 Building dependency tree...
#10 3.969 Reading state information...
#10 3.972 Package ttf-ubuntu-font-family is not available, but is referred to by another package.
#10 3.972 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
#10 3.972 is only available from another source
#10 3.972
#10 3.972 Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
#10 3.972 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
#10 3.972 is only available from another source
#10 3.972
#10 3.972 Package ttf-unifont is not available, but is referred to by another package.
#10 3.972 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
#10 3.972 is only available from another source
#10 3.972 However the following packages replace it:
#10 3.972   fonts-unifont
#10 3.972
#10 3.972 Package xfonts-cyrillic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
#10 3.972 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
#10 3.972 is only available from another source
#10 3.972
#10 3.974 E: Package 'ttf-unifont' has no installation candidate
#10 3.974 E: Package 'xfonts-cyrillic' has no installation candidate
#10 3.974 E: Package 'ttf-ubuntu-font-family' has no installation candidate
#10 3.974 E: Unable to locate package libx264-155
#10 3.974 E: Unable to locate package libenchant1c2a
#10 3.974 E: Unable to locate package libicu66
#10 3.974 E: Package 'libjpeg-turbo8' has no installation candidate
#10 3.974 E: Unable to locate package libvpx6
#10 3.974 E: Unable to locate package libwebp6
#10 3.975 Failed to install browser dependencies
#10 3.975 Error: Installation process exited with code: 100
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c playwright install-deps]: exit code: 1
```

The command I'm running is 'docker-compose build'.
Hope someone could help, Thanks.

Comment: 1. docker-compose is old, if possible move to newer docker with a so-called compose v2 (aka docker compose, not docker-compose). 2. It literally says "BEWARE: your OS is not officially supported by Playwright; installing dependencies for Ubuntu as a fallback" and then it fails on "ttf-ubuntu-font-family" and some others - obviously ubuntu package won't be in debian's repo. Docker's python image is debian bullseye. Use playwright base image (it's ubuntu-based) or any other ubuntu-based image as your base.

Comment: We had similar issue today after bumping up the python image version from `public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.10.11` to `public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.10.12`. Downgrading back to `3.10.11` worked.

Comment: This issue is tracking @ [playwright/issues/13530](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/13530)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:
I changed the base image to a newer version and now it is working properly.

```
FROM python:3.10.7
instead of:
FROM python:3.9-slim
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because on June 10th, 2023 debian release a new version ["bookworm"](https://www.debian.org/News/2023/20230610) that seems that broke the playwright integration, so in order to fix you could change the base image to `bullseye` tag, `slim` always use the latest debian stable version.

```
python:3.9-bullseye
```